# boost::pool malloc() results in segmentation fault

Tags: c++, boost, malloc, pool

Im currently stuck on some weird issues im not understanding.

I have compiled my program for unix with gcc and now im trying to run it, what happens is that
the program initializes a socket-io-service and crashes instantly because it tries to allocate memory with the boost pool.

Im trying to create a new instance of foo..

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 32; i++)
{
    foo* bar = new foo();
}
```

This is what happens when new is called:

```
void * operator new (size_t size)
{
    (void)size;
    return (void *)(mypool.malloc());  
}
```

If i use malloc(size_t) instead of m_pool.malloc() everything starts up fine..

Things i used:
GCC v11
Boost 1.59
Boost 1.65
Boost 1.81

CentOs 7
Ubuntu 22.04

I dont understand what is happening here, is it maybe some issue with x32/x64?

Or could it be the compiler?

I hope you guys can help, if needed more information please ask

I tried different systems, different boost version, i also created a simple program and manually tried the pool.. it worked

Comment: try re-compiling with address sanitiser - something like: https://www.osc.edu/resources/getting_started/howto/howto_use_address_sanitizer#:~:text=Address%20Sanitizer%20is%20a%20tool,both%20C%20and%20C%2B%2B%20codes. I.e. add `-fsanitize=address` to your compiler and linker flags. Clean, re-build and re-run - it should tell you where you have gone wrong.  Note: this is most likely your code (and not the compiler) - if it works sometimes under certain conditions this is no surprise when dealing with undefined behaviour (like bad address access)

Comment: Thanks. Ive run it with -fsanitize but it didnt showed nothing. Its not an issue with free-ing memory its more of an issue creating it and it doesn't run on any unix build so fair (x64)

Comment: very surprised that address san did not even show up the memory access error (crash). Can you output the error you see - i.e. is it a seg fault? -asan should certainly print something in this case. Are you sure you compiled AND linked with the `-fsanitize=address` flag?.   Also - what are you `new`'ing with your pool.malloc() function? - are you sure the fixed-sized malloc is large enough? - do you need a check that `size <= partition_sz`?

Comment: You need to create a minimal reproducer if we are to help debug this

Comment: My guess would be that you have multiple threads but [`boost::pool`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_81_0/libs/pool/doc/html/boost_pool/pool/interfaces.html) is not thread safe. Please show a [mre]

Comment: Ive added the output from AddressSanitizer but i dont really understand what is going on.. Looks like some some allocation size mis-match but i dont know.. So it looks like its not enough memory allocated for the object..

Comment: Please never post images of text. In this case you could argue the color has added value, but it makes it impossible to interact with in a text editor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue!

The program uses a library which runs the critical code, and what happened was that this code:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 32; i++)
{
    foo* bar = new foo;
}
```

Got executed in the constructor from a class which is a singleton.

The singleton was declared like this in the header:

```
static xy__instance;
static xy* instance()
{
    return &__instance;
}
```

So as the program was starting the frist thing that happenend was creating an instance of the singleton from the library.. (see the startup below..)

```
#9 0x7f4502d58eba in __libc_start_main_impl ../csu/libc-start.c:379
#10 0x555db2ddaa34 in _start (/home/program+0x70a34)

#0 0x7f450336f5f7 in operator new[](unsigned long, std::nothrow_t const&) ../../../../src/libsanitizer/asan/asan_new_delete.cpp:108
#1 0x555db2deb8d1 in boost::default_user_allocator_new_delete::malloc(unsigned long) /usr/local/include/boost-1_65_1/boost/pool/pool.hpp:97
#2 0x555db2ded1a9 in boost::pool<boost::default_user_allocator_new_delete>::malloc_need_resize() /usr/local/boost_1_65_1/boost/pool/pool.hpp:693
#3 0x555db2dec894 in boost::pool<boost::default_user_allocator_new_delete>::malloc() /usr/local/include/boost-1_65_1/boost/pool/pool.hpp:431
#4 0x555db2e48424 in MemoryPoo::operator new(unsigned long) (/home/program+0xde424)
#5 0x555db2e3a4fb in mySingleton::mySingleton() /home/xy.cpp:23
#6 0x555db2e3e970 in __static_initialization_and_destruction_0 /home/xy.cpp:48
#7 0x555db2e3f095 in _GLOBAL__sub_I__ZN3bnfC2Ev /home/xy.cpp:686
#8 0x7f4502d58eba in call_init ../csu/libc-start.c:145
#9 0x7f4502d58eba in __libc_start_main_impl ../csu/libc-start.c:379
```

So my thought was: A memory allocation can't happen if there is no main-thread yet.. please correct me if im wrong here because im not sure!

And then i changed the singleton to this:

```
static xy* instance()
{
    static xy __instance;
    return &__instance;
}
```

And it worked!

I think that the instance was created immediatly because it was directly
in the header and that the current gcc-compiler handles it different then in older versions..

Note that i migrated that project from C++98.
Now it runs fine and i can finally use the benefits of newer C++ versions!

Answer (score 0):

gcc44 "centos 6.10" it works outside of the function like

```
static xy__instance;
static xy* instance()
{
    return &__instance;
}
```

gcc48 and above? "centos 7.9 core" gcc 4.8.5
some reason wants it inside the function.

Thank you for this <3 saved me a headache compiling haha

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).